# How to create a dll in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

Any good website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this.

[Beginners Tutorial](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/C-DLLs-for-beginners/10913)

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(VS.80).aspx

This has a pretty good walkthrough. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

www.codeproject.com  has good example.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @SteveGuidi: Well, the question *specifically* asks for a link to a website. Whether or not this type of question is welcome or not is a different issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, your are correct.  I missed that when reviewing "flagged" posts.